# Javascript slider update during initial page load

Tags: javascript, java, css, jquery-ui-slider

I have a jsp page which contains 3 sliders.On the first page load i will be assigning some default initial values to these sliders.After this the user can change the slider values,upon which a function is called for the slider update.My problem is that when the initial default values are being set for the three sliders,the function is fired 3 times .I am a newbie to javascript and tried googling with no luck.Can somebody helpout?

Thanks

Comment: Perhaps renaming the duplicate functions to something unique but similar name?  That, or, using the jQuery `.one()` method.  It's hard to answer precisely without code a reference or sandbox.